# How to prevent a class having the same type of property more than once?

Tags: c#, class

Is there any way to prevent a class containing same type of property more than once?
Possible to give a compilation error? May be using a data annotations?

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar1 { get; set; }
    
    //Compiler should throw an error as there is a property with type Bar is already defined.
    //E.g: Error: Multiple object sets per type are not supported
    public Bar Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is just to prevent some runtime errors.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not any way built into C# or .NET.  You could make a custom analyzer that enforces this, at either the compile or static analysis step of the build process, or even catch the problem while editing.   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/

Comment: `This is just to prevent some runtime errors.` - Could you provide more details? There might be other solutions to prevent those errors